# invoke local copy of GPG for encryption

Tags: google-apps-script

Nooby to [google-apps-script] (GAS).

I wish to enhance my use of Google Drive to encrypt chosen files prior to storage on Drive and decrypt upon retrieval.

It appears from what I've seen so far that it's bad form to invoke local programs from GAS, but is it even possible from GAS to invoke a local version of GPG?

A pointer into the morass of intro-by-example-or-video for GAS to invoke a local program would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not bad practice, Its impossible as gas runs server-side.
The only client-side code that can run is client javascript from htmlService but you can't run local programs from a javascript browser for security reasons. Even if you hack your browser with command-line params and/or use a html5 feature it still wont work because 'caja' will remove it.